# Como pegar trechos de texo dentro de um site usando cURL

Tags: php, libcurl

**Tenho esse exemplo com "file_get_contents"**

**Como seria feito usando o cURL?**

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.exemplo.com/exemplo.php';
$dadosSite = file_get_contents($url);

$var1 = explode('Da linha 1 até',$dadosSite);
$var2 = explode("Linha 25",$var1[1]);

print $var2[0];
?>
```

Comment: Você não está pegando um trecho do url no seu código, você está pegando um trecho do conteúdo do site usando o explode, a sua pergunta deveria ser: como eu pego o trecho de um site usando cURL, não?

Comment: Sim exatamente, vou alterar o titulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo isso que você quer fazer se chama Web Scraping, segue abaixo um exemplo com cURL.

```
$curl = curl_init('www.pudim.com.br');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$page = curl_exec($curl);
$pattern = '#mailto:(.*?)"#';
preg_match($pattern,$page,$resultado);
echo $resultado[0];
```

Nesse pequeno pedaço de código estou indo buscar o email da página mais famosa da web.
Você pode testar o código acima neste [site](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/PHP-Curl-teste);

Comment: Obrigado amigo, exatamente isso que estava procurando